# Click-to-Call Dialing on Mobile Devices

Tags: php, android, html, mobile

How do I set up a web page (php or html) so that when a user on an Android phone lands on the page, a phone number is dialed automatically? So far this is not working for me.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://www.webpage.com'); ?>
<iframe src="tel:8663261708"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you  try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to code like this...

```
  <a href="tel:4524311551">4524311551<a>
```

If you  want to  open automatically when a page is loaded then

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="dialMe()">

<p id="demo">Testing</p>

<script>
function dialMe() {
   window.open("tel:5667828577");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it should be possible to have this tel: link, load the mobile dialer screen automatically, so you can try to call, as soon as you arrive on this page.

Comment: Yes, but it needs to happen without clicking on it... As soon as you arrive on the page, I want it to, bring the dialer app up, automatically.

Comment: I have tested the new code on my mobile Samsung Galaxy and it doesn't work, even though it does work in Google Chrome.